# switch between 1 and 0 in a list

Tags: prolog

> There is an initial list always consists of '1' (e.g.: [1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]), and the initial list will be given in the question. Then there are some people want to switch the list. The first person will switch every '1' to '0'. The second person follow the first one, and he want to switch the every second number to another(if he meets '0', he switch it to '1';if he meets '1', he switch it to '0'). The third person follow the first one, and he want to switch the every third number to another. Of course, the number of people will be given in the question. Please give the result of final statement of the list.
>
> Write a program 'switch(1,N,Initial,Final). N is the count of people.
>
> For example :

```
switch(1,2,[1,1],Final).       Final=[0,1].

switch(1,3,[1,1,1],Final).     Final=[0,1,1].
```

Comment: "what have you tried?", I typed. The system responded: "Comments cannot contain that content.

If the author didn't show what was tried, why do you assume they tried anything? Either ask for a specific bit of information, suggest a specific improvement, or downvote and move on." -- getting this pop-up was an *interesting* experience...

Comment: @WillNess I have been using a circumlocution like "Please share your attempt with us so we can help you get unstuck"

Comment: curiously, those who put that message into words seem to dispute that 0 is a number too, basically -- arguably the most important discovery the Humanity made which allowed all of the current scientific progress to occur in the first place. such people are now in charge over the site here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we've got a bunch of people who, with nothing better to do in
their lives, want to sequentially switch some numbers in a list. Someone needs to introduce them to Prolog, they could make better use of their time. But this is our initial recursion and base case:

```
switch(N, N, In, Out) :-
    person_switch(N, 1, In, Out), !.
switch(P, N, In, Out) :-
    person_switch(P, 1, In, Done),
    succ(P, Q),
    switch(Q, N, Done, Out).
```

So we can make our people do their switch sequentially via the first argument, which we increment until we reach the base case.

Next up, we'd better teach these people how to do their jobs of switching 0's and 1's.

```
person_switch(_, _, [], []). % Base case
person_switch(P, P, [1|In], [0|Out]) :- % switch 1 to a 0 on their turn
    person_switch(P, 1, In, Out). % Recurse
person_switch(P, P, [0|In], [1|Out]) :- % switch 0 to a 1 on their turn
    person_switch(P, 1, In, Out). % Recurse
person_switch(P, C, [H|In], [H|Out]) :- % don't switch, unify
    C < P, % don't not switch when they should, C is a counter along the list
    succ(C, D), % increment
    person_switch(P, D, In, Out). % Recurse
```

Good luck learning Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

```
:- [library(plunit)] .

switch(_one_,_two_,_source_,_target_) :-
    switch('induce',_one_,_two_,_source_,_target_,1) .

switch('swap',false,0,0) .
switch('swap',false,1,1) .
switch('swap',true,0,1) .
switch('swap',true,1,0) .

switch('induce',_one_,_two_,_source_,_target_,_nth_) :-
    _source_ = [] ,
    _target_ = [] ;
    _source_ = [_car_|_cdr_] ,
    _target_ = [_CAR_|_CDR_] ,
    _NTH_ is _nth_ + 1 ,
    switch('induce',_one_,_two_,_cdr_,_CDR_,_NTH_) ,
    switch('deduce',_one_,_two_,_car_,_CAR_,_nth_) .

switch('deduce',_one_,_two_,_car_,_CAR_,_nth_) :-
    _one_ = _nth_ ,
    switch('swap',true,_car_,_CAR_) ;
    _one_ \= _nth_ ,
    _two_ = _nth_ ,
    switch('swap',true,_car_,_CAR_) ;
    _one_ \= _nth_ ,
    _two_ \= _nth_ ,
    switch('swap',false,_car_,_CAR_) .
```

%

```
:- begin_tests(switch).

test(switch,[nondet,true(Final == [0,0])])       :- switch(1,2,[1,1],Final) .
test(switch,[nondet,true(Final == [0,1,0])])     :- switch(1,3,[1,1,1],Final) .
test(switch,[nondet,true(Final == [0,1,1,0])])   :- switch(1,4,[1,1,1,1],Final) .
test(switch,[nondet,true(Final == [0,1,1,1,0])]) :- switch(1,5,[1,1,1,1,1],Final) .
test(switch,[nondet,true(Final == [1,1,1,1,1])]) :- switch(1,5,[0,1,1,1,0],Final) .

:- end_tests(switch).
```

%

```
/*
$ yap -f stackoverflow_switch_list.prolog -g 'run_tests' ;
YAP 6.2.2 (i686-linux): Sat Aug 17 14:01:16 UTC 2019
% PL-Unit: switch ..... done
% All 5 tests passed
yes
   ?- 
*/
```